# Error: not conform to protocol 'Equatable'

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I'm new to swift and following a tutorial to learn more.

In The following code, I have defined custom operators (< and ==) and however  the code works fine but Xcode shows these errors in the 1st line of code.

```
Type 'SuitedCard' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'
Type 'SuitedCard' does not conform to protocol 'Comparable'
```

here is the code:

```
struct SuitedCard: Equatable, Comparable {

    // a card can be ♥️, ♣️, ♦️, ♠️
    enum Suit {
        case hearts
        case spades
        case diamonds
        case clubs
    }

    // the possible values of a card
    enum Value: Int {
        case two = 2
        case three = 3
        case four = 4
        case five = 5
        case six = 6
        case seven = 7
        case eight = 8
        case nine = 9
        case ten = 10
        case jack = 11
        case queen = 12
        case king = 13
        case ace = 14
    }

    // properties
    let suit: Suit
    let value: Value
    var isFaceDown: Bool
}

var valueArray: [SuitedCard.Value] = [.ten, .jack, .queen, .king]


func ==(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
    for cardValue in valueArray {
        if lhs.value == cardValue {
            for cardValue2 in valueArray {
                if rhs.value == cardValue2 {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if lhs.value == rhs.value {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func <(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
    var lhsRawValue: Int
    var rhsRawValue: Int
    if lhs.value == .jack || lhs.value == .queen || lhs.value == .king {
        lhsRawValue = 10
    } else {
        lhsRawValue = lhs.value.rawValue
    }
    if rhs.value == .jack || rhs.value == .queen || rhs.value == .king {
        rhsRawValue = 10
    } else {
        rhsRawValue = rhs.value.rawValue
    }
    return lhsRawValue < rhsRawValue
}

let smaller = SuitedCard(suit: .hearts, value: .five, isFaceDown: true)

let bigger = SuitedCard(suit: .diamonds, value: .six, isFaceDown: false)

smaller >= smaller

smaller < bigger
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3, operators required for protocols are declared as static members.

One way to work with such protocols is moving your operator definitions into the struct as static member:

```
struct SuitedCard: Comparable { //### Comparable implies Equatable

    //...

    // function for custom operator ==
    static func ==(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
        //...
        return false
    }
    // function for custom operator <
    static func <(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
        //...
        return false
    }
}
```

---

Another way, you can declare the conformance to the protocol using extension:

```
struct SuitedCard {

    //...
}

// function for custom operator ==
func ==(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
    //...
    return false
}
// function for custom operator <
func <(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
    //...
    return false
}

extension SuitedCard: Comparable {}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5 Equatable and Comparable Protocol:

```
// Car Model
struct Car {
    let name: String
    let id: Int
    let weight: Double
}

// MARK: - Compare if to object are equal if specific parameter(s) are equal.
extension Car: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        if lhs.id == rhs.id {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Equatable examples

```
let carsList: [Car] = []
let favouriteCar: Car = Car(name: "Brand", id: 1, weight: 4000)

// Ex. 1
if carsList.contains(favouriteCar) {
    print("Favourite car is ready to be delivered!")
}

// Ex. 2
if carsList.first == favouriteCar {
    print("Favourite car is first to be delivered!")
}
```

Comparable protocol

```
// MARK: - Compare to object from specific parameter(s) using the relational operators <, <=, >=, and >.
extension Car: Comparable {
    static func < (lhs: Car, rhs: Car) -> Bool {
        if lhs.weight < rhs.weight {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comparable  Example

```
let carsList: [Car] = []
let favouriteCar: Car = Car(name: "Brand", id: 1, weight: 4000)

if carsList.first < favouriteCar {
    print("First car in the lighter compare to favourite car!")
} else if carsList.first > favouriteCar {
    print("First car in the heavier compare to favourite car!")
} else {
    print("First car and favourite car have the same weight!")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer by OOPer solves the problem but in Swift 3, operator methods can be defined outside of the class/struct body too. So in this case, just moving the valueArray declaration into the body of == method solves the problem. Here is the corrected code:

```
struct SuitedCard: Equatable, Comparable {

    // a card can be ♥️, ♣️, ♦️, ♠️
    enum Suit {
        case hearts
        case spades
        case diamonds
        case clubs
    }

    // the possible values of a card
    enum Value: Int {
        case two = 2
        case three = 3
        case four = 4
        case five = 5
        case six = 6
        case seven = 7
        case eight = 8
        case nine = 9
        case ten = 10
        case jack = 11
        case queen = 12
        case king = 13
        case ace = 14
    }

    // properties
    let suit: Suit
    let value: Value
    var isFaceDown: Bool
}


func ==(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
```

//declaration of valueArray moved here:

```
    let valueArray: [SuitedCard.Value] = [.ten, .jack, .queen, .king]
    for cardValue in valueArray {
        if lhs.value == cardValue {
            for cardValue2 in valueArray {
                if rhs.value == cardValue2 {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if lhs.value == rhs.value {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func <(lhs: SuitedCard, rhs: SuitedCard) -> Bool {
    var lhsRawValue: Int
    var rhsRawValue: Int
    if lhs.value == .jack || lhs.value == .queen || lhs.value == .king {
        lhsRawValue = 10
    } else {
        lhsRawValue = lhs.value.rawValue
    }
    if rhs.value == .jack || rhs.value == .queen || rhs.value == .king {
        rhsRawValue = 10
    } else {
        rhsRawValue = rhs.value.rawValue
    }
    return lhsRawValue < rhsRawValue
}

let smaller = SuitedCard(suit: .hearts, value: .five, isFaceDown: true)

let bigger = SuitedCard(suit: .diamonds, value: .six, isFaceDown: false)

smaller >= smaller

smaller < bigger
```